# $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)\cap L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $f''\in L^2(\mathbb R)$. How do I show $f(\infty)=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

My purpose is to show that, for $f\in L^2$ with $f''\in L^2$,there is a sequence $f_j\in C_0^\infty$ such that $\|f_j-f\|_2+\|f''_j-f''\|_2\to 0$.

※$C_0(\mathbb R)=\{f\in C(\mathbb R):f(\infty)=0\}$

I let $G_j=\frac{j}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(jx)^2/2}$ and let $f_j=G_j*f$. Since $G_j$ is smooth, $G_j*f\to f$ and $G_j''*f=G_j*f''\to f''$ both converge.

However, I do not know  how to show $G_j*f\in C_0$.

Comment: This depends entirely on your domain of $f$... . And I would recommend you to take a better sequence $G_j$.

Comment: @Meowdog domain is $\mathbb R$. which sequence is better?

Comment: Well if your domain is $\mathbb{R}$, chances are that $G_j * f$ is simply untrue

Comment: The title asks for proof of $f(\infty)=0$ but the question asks for proof of $G_j*f \in C_0$. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy wouldn't the title imply that $G_j*f\in C_0$?

Comment: Usually one chooses $\eta(x): = \chi_{[-1, 1]} \exp\left( \frac{1}{x^2-1} \right)$ and $G(j) := C j \eta(jx)$ where $C^{-1} := \int_{-1}^1 \eta(x)~\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @Meowdog Thank you, I will try this. but I think $G_j$ also works?

Comment: It might, but you could have trouble if you want to show compact support. Take for example $f = 1$

Comment: @Meowdog yes the support is not compact. I only need $C_0$ here.

Comment: Ah you mean continuity by $C_0$? We might have a notation misunderstanding...

Comment: @Meowdog I mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$. or, for every $\epsilon>0$, $f^{-1}([-\epsilon,\epsilon])$ is compact.

Comment: I am really not sure if this is true... . It would clearly be for $L^1$, but about $L^2$ I am not sure

Comment: @Meowdog I know how to prove it now. $G_r*f=[\hat {G_r}\hat f]^\vee$ and $\hat {G_r}\in L^2$. Therefore $\hat{G_r}\hat f\in L^1$, and $[\hat{G_r}\hat f]^\vee\in C_0$.

Comment: @Meowdog I thought that $f''\in L^2$ was necessary...

Comment: I think this is not enough... . This proves that $G(x-y)f(y) \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$ since we integrate w.r.t. $y$. But this is different from $G(x-y)f(y) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Meowdog are you sure? I think this proves $(G*f)(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$

Comment: But why should it?

Comment: @Meowdog $(G_r*f)(x)=\int e^{2\pi x\xi} \hat{G_r}(\xi)\hat f(\xi) d\xi$ and Riemann-Lebesgue theorem shows $(G_r*f)(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ if $\hat{G_r}(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)\in L^1$. Since they both $\in L^2$, this is true.  isn't this correct?

Comment: @Meowdog and it seems the title follows from sobolev embedding theorem